# jQuery load template inside a loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a json file with some data and I am using a Js loop to load a jQuery template to iterate through and load a table made of 4 rows based on the data, so far I only get the last row. https://github.com/codepb/jquery-template

```
<script type="text/html" id="tableContent">
  <tr>
    <th>Key</th>
    <th>Product</th>
    <th>Bookings</th>
    <th>%</th>
    <th>Transactions</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td data-content="">sth</td>
    <td data-content="Product"></td>
    <td data-content="Bookings"></td>
    <td data-content="Percentage"></td>
    <td data-content="Transactions"></td>
  </tr>
</script>

      function builTable(){
          var table = "",
              colors = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4', 'col5', 'col6'];

          for(i = 0; i< source.Products.length; i++){

            $("table").loadTemplate($("#tableContent"),

{


            Product: source.Products[i].Product,
            Bookings: source.Products[i].Bookings,
            Percentage: source.Products[i].Percentage,
            Transaction: source.Products[i].Transaction

} ); 

  $(document).ready(function(){

    builTable();

  });

<table border="1" cellpadding="2">



</table>
```

Is there something wrong inside the loop?

http://jsfiddle.net/9JV7t/1/

Comment: Your jsfiddle code doesn't work.

Comment: May be loading template is asynchronous

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need to add an array because it loads the whole content just once and then overrides it again. But therefore you need to only include the data rows in the template and add the headings to the table ([**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/9JV7t/3/)):

```
<script type="text/html" id="tableContent">
    <tr>
        <td data-content="">sth</td>
        <td data-content="Product"></td>
        <td data-content="Bookings"></td>
        <td data-content="Percentage"></td>
        <td data-content="Transactions"></td>
    </tr>
</script>
```

Your table:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Key</th>
            <th>Product</th>
            <th>Bookings</th>
            <th>%</th>
            <th>Transactions</th>
        </tr>    
    </thead>
    <tbody>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

And the js:

```
function builTable(){
     $("tbody").loadTemplate($("#tableContent"), source.Products); 
}
```